# Handling nodes that does exists while parsing

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

I have the XML response of API that looks like below

```
<lab:lab uri="https://bh03.org/api/lb/3" xmlns:udf="http://ge.com/ri/userdefined" xmlns:ri="http://ge.com/ri" xmlns:lab="http://ge.com/ri/lab">
    <name>GTech</name>
    <udf:field type="String" name="Account ID">gt</udf:field>
</lab:lab>
```

I want to get the value 'gt' of Account ID from the XML so I am using XDocument Parse and using the below code

```
XDocument new_doc = XDocument.Parse(responseString_LabURL);
XNamespace ns = "http://ge.com/ri/userdefined";
string accountID = new_doc.Descendants(ns + "field").FirstOrDefault(field => field.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("Account ID")).Value;
```

But sometimes there will be no `<udf:field type="String" name="Account ID">gt</udf:field>` in the XML and might look like the below

```
<lab:lab uri="https://bh03.org/api/v2/labs/1302" xmlns:udf="http://ge.com/ri/userdefined" xmlns:ri="http://ge.com/ri" xmlns:lab="http://ge.com/ri/lab">
    <name>lsd</name>
</lab:lab>
```

How to handle when there is no field.

Comment: Two suggestions 1) Don't use "string' as type use var.  String doesn't like null values. 2) Don't use Value which as gives errors when null.  Instead try this : string accountID = new_doc.Descendants(ns + "field").Where(field => field.Attribute("name") != null).Select(x => (string)field.Attribute("name")).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 1):

I would start testing if the element `<udf:field></udf:field>` exists. Like this:

```
string accountID;
XDocument new_doc = XDocument.Parse(responseString_LabURL);
XNamespace ns = "http://ge.com/ri/userdefined";

if (new_doc.Descendants(ns + "field").Any())
{
    accountID = new_doc.Descendants(ns + "field").FirstOrDefault(field => field.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("Account ID")).Value;
}
else
{
    accountID = null; // or whatever
}
```

Shorthand for the above code is:

```
accountID = new_doc.Descendants(ns + "field").Any() ? new_doc.Descendants(ns + "field").FirstOrDefault(field => field.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("Account ID")).Value : null;
```